# Link JavaScript code to an R Shiny widget

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

**Summary:** I would like to adapt a JavaScript library (namely OwlCarousel2) in R, and more precisely in R Shiny. I have made several steps so far, but I can't find a way to append the JS script necessary at the end of the HTML structure (just before the end of body).

---

`OwlCarousel2` is a library that allows to create cards and to make them slide. See [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html) for more details.

**What I've done so far:**

- First of all, I checked that I could reproduce the expected behavior of this library only with HTML, CSS and JS, following [this tutorial](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/2020/06/owl-carousel-cards-slider-in-html-css-jquery.html).
- Then I tried to adapt this in R Shiny. Basically, I created functions embedding the raw HTML, I put the JS and CSS in `www`, and I ran the app to be sure it worked. It did: the cards were displayed, and there was the slide behavior. But this was a bit messy so I decided to turn it into a package, so that I (and others) could re-use it more easily.
- To transform this into a package, I used two sources:

  1. the [tutorial](https://github.com/gadenbuie/applause#dev-log) that accompanies the package `{applause}`
  2. this [new book](https://book.javascript-for-r.com/) about R and Javascript

I made three functions: `owl_carousel_item()` to create cards, `owl_carousel()` to embed the cards into a `div` with the class `slider owl-carousel`, and `html_dependency_owlcarousel()` to include the dependencies.

```
html_dependency_owlcarousel <- function() {
  htmltools::htmlDependency(
    name = "owl.carousel",
    version = "2.3.4",
    package = "shinymisc",
    src = "htmlwidgets/owl_carousel",
    script = c("owl.carousel.min.js", "owl.carousel.js"),
    stylesheet = c("owl.carousel.min.css", "style.css"),
    all_files = FALSE
  )
}

owl_carousel <- function(id, ...) {

  tag <- htmltools::tags$div(
    id = id,
    class = "slider owl-carousel",
    ...
  )

  htmltools::tagList(
    tag,
    html_dependency_owlcarousel()
  )
}

owl_carousel_item <- function(title, subtitle, content = NULL, button_text = NULL, width = "300px") {

  if (!is.null(button_text))
    button <- shiny::tags$div(class = "btn", value = button_text)
  else
    button <- NULL

  shiny::tags$div(
    class = "card",
    style = paste0("width: ", width),
    shiny::tags$div(class = "img"),
    shiny::tags$div(
      class = "content",
      shiny::tags$div(class = "title", title),
      shiny::tags$div(class = "sub-title", subtitle),
      shiny::tags$p(content),
      button
    )
  )

}
```

With this code (and the dependencies), I produce an app that has an HTML structure almost equivalent to the one I could create outside the package environment: it displays the cards, but they don't slide. The thing that is missing is the `<script>` that should be at the bottom of this structure, just before the end of `<body>`. This is why the cards don't slide.

I tried to apply the method described in [this chapter](https://book.javascript-for-r.com/widgets-realistic.html) of the book previously mentioned, but not success because I couldn't make `htmlwidgets::createWidget()` work with my `tag`.

**Therefore, my question is: how can I place the following script at the end of the HTML structure?**

```
$(".slider").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000, //2000ms = 2s;
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
  });
```

Keep in mind that these options should be editable through the function `owl_carousel()` (so just pasting this at the end of `tag` in `owl_carousel()` is not enough).

I know that this must not be very clear, so here's the [link to the repo](https://github.com/etiennebacher/shinymisc) containing what I've made so far.

**Note:** this should be less hard than for other widgets. Here's there is no `*Output` or `render*` functions, no data, just a function to embed boxes and make them slide.

**Edit:** some code to test that it works (it should display two cards and an animation):

```
library(shiny)
library(fullPage)

ui <- fullPage(
  menu = c("Section 1" = "section1"),
  pageSection(
    menu = "section1",
    owl_carousel(
      id = "test",
      owl_carousel_item(
        title = "test1",
        subtitle = "subtitle1",
        content = "this is a test"
      ),
      owl_carousel_item(
        title = "test2", 
        subtitle = "subtitle2", 
        content = "this is a test", 
        button_text = "button to click"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe adding a `htmltools::tags$script('ur jquery code here')` to the taglist

Comment: Thanks, this works for `shiny::fluidPage` but not for other layouts, such as `fullPage::fullPage` because the script seems to be "too high" in the HTML structure. Moreover, it doesn't seem like a clean way to link javascript to a function in a package.

Comment: can you provide a MWE so I can test it. also thanks for making shiny better

Comment: also maybe if you wait for the content to be loaded will that work

Comment: I already know how to make this work in a "classic" setting. Here, my problem is due to the fact that it is an R package, and that the structure is very different. Therefore, I can't produce an MWE. However, you can download the repo I linked in my post to have the exact situation in which I am.

Comment: I think the `htmlwidgets::createWidget()` is not working due to the missing `inst/htmlwidgets/owl_carousel.js` file which is used to interface between js and R

Comment: I moved `owl_carousel.js` from `inst/htmlwidgets/owl_carousel` to `inst/htmlwidgets` but then I have the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was moving the `owl_carousel.js` into `inst/htmlwidgets` and modifying the `renderValue` function to include the provided `jQuery` code.

```js
renderValue: function(x) {

  // TODO: code to render the widget, e.g.
  el.innerHTML = x.message;

  $(".slider").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000, //2000ms = 2s;
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
  })

}
```

And changing the return value of the `owl_carousel` function to :

```r
owl_carousel <- function(id, ..., width = "100%", height = "400px") {

  tag <- htmltools::tags$div(
    id = id,
    class = "slider owl-carousel",
    ...
  )
  
  x <- list(message=as.character(htmltools::tagList(
    tag,
    html_dependency_owlcarousel()
  )))
  htmlwidgets::createWidget(
     name = 'owl_carousel',
     x,
     package = 'shinymisc'
   )
}
```

**Edit**
For the css issue you haven't included `style.css` in the yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
 - name: jQuery
   version: 3.5.1
   src: htmlwidgets/jquery
   script: jquery.min.js
 - name: OwlCarousel2
   version: 2.3.4
   src: htmlwidgets/owl_carousel
   script: owl.carousel.min.js
   stylesheet:
    - owl.carousel.min.css
    - style.css
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: This does not work. I added an example in my post to easily test if the code works or not. In this example, after applying your modifications, there are no errors but nothing is displayed

Comment: @bretauv the error is rising from jquery not finding the `owlCarousel` function maybe there is a clash between the jQuery version used by `fullPage` and that used by `owlCarousel`

Comment: fullPage uses jQuery 3.2 and owlCarousel use 3.5

Comment: it works when printing the widget and with `shiny::fluidPage`

Comment: Indeed, I had to open it in the browser. However, the css style is not applied (whereas it was before). Could you make a fork of the repo so that I can have exactly what you have?

Comment: @bretauv I forked the repo and the only changes I did are the ones mentioned in the answer running `devtools::install_github("moutikabdessabour/shinymisc@shiny-patch")` will install the branch and I'm 75% certain that there is a conflict between fullpage.js code and owlcarousel's cuz if you check the console in your browser you'll see 2-3 error messages that pop only when fullpage js is used

Comment: I don't understand, I downloaded your fork, restarted the session, used `fluidPage`, but the css is still not applied. But I need to figure out how to solve this for `fullPage` too anyway. I really appreciate your help, you gave me some hints to solve this in the future, but I can't validate the solution. Hopefully I will find something and will propose a clean package in future ;)

Comment: @bretauv For the css you didn't include the style.css file please check the edit

Comment: Thanks! I prefer to wait a little before validating this answer, just to confirm that this works well in several situations. Comment here to notify me if I haven't done it in few days